# When accessing attribute of subtype, Hibernate skips instances of supertype

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpql

Given the following model

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Super {
    private int id;
    private String general;
    //...
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ID")
public class Sub extends Super {
    private String special;
    //...
}
```

And the following data

```
+----+----------+
|  Super        |
+---------------+
| id | general  |
+---------------+
|  1 | General1 |
|  2 | General2 |
+----+----------+

+----+----------+
|  Sub          |
+---------------+
| id | special  |
+---------------+
|  2 | Special2 |
+----+----------+
```

Using Hibernate 3.6.5, I want to achieve the following:

Return Sub.special, if available, otherwise Super.general.

So I wrote

```sql
SELECT 
  s.id,
  CASE TYPE(s)
    WHEN Sub THEN s.special
    ELSE s.general
  END
FROM Super s
```

My expected result was

```
+---------------+
|  1 | General1 |
|  2 | Special2 |
+----+----------+
```

But what was actually returned was only

```
+---------------+
|  2 | Special2 |
+----+----------+
```

So instances of supertype are not included in the result.
Apparently, this is because an attribute of the subtype is used somewhere in the SELECT clause.

Any ideas, how to get the expected result as above, without using a subquery or an outer join?

EDIT3 / clarification:

When using CASE TYPE and selecting something that is not bound to the subtype, all works perfectly.

```
SELECT 
  s.id,
  CASE TYPE(s)
    WHEN Sub THEN  'Hooray, I'm a sub-instance'
    ELSE 'Shoot, I'm no sub-instance'
  END
FROM Super s
```

leads to

```
+----------------+
|  1 | Shoot...  |
|  2 | Hooray... |
+----+-----------+
```

I do not need static text but the value of a property of subclass here.

- EDIT1: added @Inheritance to super- and subclass.
- EDIT2: added @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
- EDIT3: added SELECT that does not use property of subclass, s.t. both tuples are returned.

Comment: Maybe selecting the whole objects with a simple "FROM Super s" query is an option for you. You could then handle the different cases in your java code.

Answer (score 1):

Mapping strategies should be defined if hibernate inheritance mapping wanted to be used.

There are 3 inheritance strategies

- The Table per Concrete Class Strategy
- The Joined Subclass Strategy
- Single Table Strategy

You should add `@Inheritance` annotation and select one of inheritance strategies above according to your needs and database structure.

**See also**

[Entity inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html)

[Hibernate inheritance mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html)

Comment: Thank you for your input.
However, the @Inheritance is specified (OP updated) and cannot be changed.
So this unfortunately does not solve my problem.

Comment: you should apply @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation if you used joined subclass strategy accordingly. Please see my posts carefully.

Comment: Adding @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn did not alter the result.
I edited the OP again to include an example of when both instances are returned. But this only works when I do not access any property of subtype.